# drop down list is not getting populated in django, when data if fetched from databse

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i want data from my database to display on the dropdown list , when user click on it, but its not happening my code is all correct , i am not able to find any mistakes please help me.

this is my booking.html file

```
<!-- booking.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book a Court</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }

        header {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        form {
            display: grid;
            gap: 15px;
        }

        label {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        input,
        select {
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
      
    <header>
        <h1>Book Your Slot</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="{% url 'book' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            
            <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="id_name" name="name" required>

            <label for="id_mobile_number">Mobile Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="id_mobile_number" name="mobile_number" required>

            <label for="id_court">Court:</label>
            <select id="id_court" name="court" required>
                {% for  court in courts %}
                    <option value="{{ court}}">{{ court }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <label for="id_time_slot">Time Slot:</label>
            <select id="id_time_slot" name="time_slot" required>
                {% for slot in time_slots %}
                    <option value="{{ slot}}">{{ slot}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <button type="submit">Book Now</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my view.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from .models import Person, Court ,TimeSlot

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, "booking/index.html",{
        
    })

def bookingview(request):
    return render(request,"booking/booking.html",{
        
    })


    
    

def booked(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        courts = Court.objects.all()
        time_slots = TimeSlot.objects.all()

        return render(request,"booking/booking.html", {
        "courts": courts,
        "time_slots": time_slots,
    })
    
    
    elif  request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number')
        court=request.POST.get('court')
        timeslot=request.POST.get('time_slot')
        bookk=Person(name=name,
                     mobile_number=mobile_number,
                     court=court,
                     time_slot=timeslot)
        bookk.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(index))
```

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Court(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    time = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.time

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    court = models.ForeignKey(Court, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_slot = models.ForeignKey(TimeSlot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("booking", views.bookingview, name="booking"),
    path("book", views.booked, name="book"),
    
    
    
 

]
```

i try all the ways but its not happening, so help me please, help me soon

Comment: Can you include a screenshot when you navigate to /book/ ?

Comment: @godd0t thank you brother the problem is solved , when i write /book in url it worked, but it was not working in /booking and i want it there, so now i changed the code and and its now working on /booking, thank you love you, are you on insta?